# How to map object properties in an Orika custom mapper?

Tags: orika

I tried to find an answer to this question in the [Orika documentation](http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/) but no luck.

I have the following classes:

```
public class A {
    private String partNumber1;
    private String partNumber2;
    ...
}

public class B {
    private Integer shelfNumber;
    private A a;
    ...
}

public class BDTO {
    private Integer selfNumber;
    private ADTO someA;
    ...
}

public class ADTO {
    private String partNumber;
    ...
}
```

.. and the following CustomMapper's to map Objects of B to objects BDO

```
@Component
public class BMapper extends CustomMapper<B, BDTO> {
    @Override
    public void mapAtoB(B b, BDTO bdto, MappingContext context) {
        super.mapAtoB(b, bdto, context);
        //??? what to do here ???  
    }
}

@Component
public class AMapper extends CustomMapper<A, ADTO> {
    @Override
    public void mapAtoB(A a, ADTO adto, MappingContext context) {
        super.mapAtoB(a, adto, context);
        adto.setPartNumber(a.getPartNumber1() + a.getPartNumber2());
    }
}
```

In my client code I have:

```
B b = new B(5, new A("100392", "100342"));
BDTO bdto = mapper.map(b, BDTO.class);
```

My question is, in BMapper, what is the correct way to get the AMapper to map "a" to "someA"? To put it differently, what is the correct way to map a to someA in BMapper? I suspect that it can be done through some interface in the MappingContext object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer after some experimentation. To map property objects in the main objects mapper, i.e. the scenario explained above, one can use the protected "mapperFacade" member of CustomMapper.

So you can do something like this:

```
bdto.setSomeA(super.mapperFacade.map(b.getA(), ADTO.class));
```